# Head First C reverse string example

Tags: c

I have been going through 'Head First C' and I found exercise to create a method for reversing strings.

This was my solution:

```
void reverse_string(char s[]) {
    for (int i = strlen(s) - 1; i > -1; i--) {
       printf("%c", s[i]);
   }
}
```

And this was solution from the book:

```
void reverse_string(char *s) {
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    char *t = s + len - 1;

    while (t >= s) {
     printf("%c", *t);
     t = t - 1;
    }

    puts("");
}
```

I understand the solution from the book, but mine looks cleaner. Is the later solution preferable, and if it is, why?

Comment: Both are correct and neither are wrong. The one from the book might be preferable for the context of the book, but it doesn't mean you can't use your solution. However, there is a small difference between your solution and the books solution: Your solution doesn't print a newline.

Comment: yeah, I like your version more.

Comment: In case your code works, and you want a review, you may prefer to go to [codereview.se].

Comment: The result of `strlen()` is `size_t`, not `int`. Both versions are not optimal ... there is no need to use `printf()` which has to parse a format string just to output a single character at a time. Use `putchar()` or `fputc()`. The code from the book could have used a `for()`-loop for better readability. `void reverse_string(char const *str) { for (char const *p = str + strlen(str) - 1; p >= str; --p) { putchar(*p); } putchar('\n'); }`

Comment: ^ - Yes. The hidden `size_t` to `int` conversion in your code leaves a vulnerability in your function for very large strings. The book version doesn't suffer from it.

Comment: I have concerns that the book solution tries to decrement the pointer `t` until it points before the start of the array `s`.  It is not guaranteed that you can do that.  Both functions are misnamed; neither reverses the string, though both print the string in reverse.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good point. It should be `void print_reverse(char const *str) { for (char const *p = str + strlen(str); p != str; putchar(*--p)); putchar('\n'); }` then.

Comment: Both have undefined behaviour if passed the empty string. (The "Head First" books I've looked at weren't very good - the authors seemed more interested in funny references to contemporary popular culture than in teaching.)

Comment: I'm kinda partial to `size_t j = strlen (s); for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++) putchar (s[--j]); putchar ('\n');`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Why `j` \*and\* `i`? `for (size_t i = strlen(s); i; putchar(s[--i])); putchar('\n');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize the comments made:

First of all the function name `reverse_string()` is misleading since it doesn't reverse the string but only prints it in reverse order.

The function should take a pointer to `const char` rather than a pointer to `char`. Some also might argue that using `[]` in a parameter list is somewhat misleading since it might lead people not very familiar with C to believe that an array gets passed instead of a pointer to its first element.

Both functions use `printf()` to print a single character. This involves unnecessary work of parsing the format-string just to output a single character at a time. Use ´putchar()`or`fputc()` instead.

A functional difference between the two functions: your version doesn't print a newline after the reversed string. The version from the book does that but like using `printf()` for a single character it does so in a disguising manner using `puts("")` instead of `putchar('\n')`.

The version from the book has potentially undefined behaviour when an empty string is passed to the function since in this case `t` will point before the first element of the array pointed to by `s` which isn't guaranteed to work.

Your version uses an `int`eger to store the result of `strlen()` which is of type `size_t`. It is possible that the `int`eger will overflow for very long strings.

Two possible solutions:

```
#include <string.h>  // strlen()
#include <stdio.h>   // putchar()

void print_reverse(char const *str)
{
    for (char const *p = str + strlen(str); p != str; putchar(*--p)); 
    putchar('\n');
}
```

or using an index:

```
#include <string.h>  // strlen()
#include <stdio.h>   // putchar()

void print_reverse(char const *str)
{
    for (size_t i = strlen(str); i; putchar(str[--i])); 
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution from the book has undefined behavior because it decrements `t` beyond the beginning of the string. Comparing `t` pointing outside the array and `s` has undefined behavior. It would fail on architectures with segmented pointers where `>=` only tests the offset part of the pointer. It would also fail for an empty string for the same reason.

A portable solution with pointers would look like this:

```
void reverse_string(const char *s) {
    const char *t = s + strlen(s);

    while (t > s) {
        t--;
        putchar(*t);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Your version uses an index, which is OK, but is has a small problem: it does not handle strings longer than `INT_MAX`. The length of a string has type `size_t` which may be larger than `int`, indeed even on architectures where `int` and `size_t` have the same size, `size_t` being unsigned may have values larger than `INT_MAX`.

Changing the type `i` is not sufficient because you rely on `i` becoming negative. Here is an elegant way to test before decrementing the index:

```
void reverse_string(char s[]) {
    for (size_t i = strlen(s); i-- > 0;) {
        putchar(s[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Some facetious programmers write this comparison `i --> 0` and call `-->` the *downto* operator... It is a joke, the expression is parsed as `i` `--` `>` `0`, intervening spaces don't matter.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, none of the solutions reverse the string. They print it in reversed order, but this is not the same as reversing.

Your solution looks nicer and is concise without loosing readability, which is good.

I would not say the solution from the book is preferable.

Comment: Neither are entirely preferable as they use the variadic `printf` where a simple `putchar()` is called for.